# Make logback in SL4J show relative time (%r) in hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: logback, slf4j

I know that `%r` in logback outputs the relative time from the start of the logging event in milliseconds. How can I set it in a pattern like `HH.mm.ss.SSS`?

Unfortunately, something along the lines of `%r{HH.mm.ss.SSS}` (which is the way I do it for the current date/time `%d`) doesn't work. I can of course build a `StopWatch` object and manually output its value every time I call the logger, but this way seems rather unpractical.

Comment: Interesting idea. Please create a Jira issue asking for this feature at https://jira.qos.ch/

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I assume that then there's no way currently. I posted an issue tagged as improvement, let's see what happens: https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1272